# Does an event fire when a select element is dropped down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know when the element has been dropped down.

I don't want to wait until a value has been selected.

Is there an event I can hook into?

I'm happy to use JQuery/ Javascript to accomplish this

Thanks

**UPDATE**:
Thanks for the suggestions.

`focus` isn't quite right as it fires when the user tabs into the element;

`click` meets my needs as (although as @billyonecan says it doesn't fire for a keyboard dropdown) I am only interested in mouse-initiated dropdowns (the bug I'm addressing doesn't happen for keyboard-users).

For the record I am interested in the items being dropped down, not an item being selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/fjqmj/16/ shows a comparison of all the suggestions.

Comment: You can use click event.

Comment: post your html code and script that you have tried so far

Comment: Using the `.on('click')` event instead of the `.click()' event makes the handler reusable for all similar elements on your page (rather than an individual handler for each select element.

Comment: what are your goals for this event? Try using focus handler

Comment: `click` event won't work if the select is expanded via a keypress (space bar, alt + down etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    <select id="selectOption">
     <option value="1">One</option>
     <option value="2">two</option>
    </select>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectOption').click(function(){
     alert('clicked');
  });
});
```

Comment: With the `alert()', the user can never select an option. Without the `alert()`, the event will fire twice (once for select being clicked and once for an option being clicked)

Comment: ``$(document).ready(function()`` and ``$(function()`` is the same thing, you should remove one of them

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<select id="selectOption">
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

jQuery :

```
$(function(){
  $('#selectOption').focus(function(){
     alert('clicked');
  });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fjqmj/13/)**

Comment: This will not work in all cases: If the user makes his choice and decides to select another option it will not fire since the dropdown is already focused.

Comment: @EugenTimm, yes in that case this will not fire. I think OP should comment and tell us what exactly he wants to do with opened drop down.

Comment: @EugenTimm OP stated they aren't looking for change

Comment: It depends if that is the desired use case @EugenTimm, the OP's question reads that he wants alerted to when a user enters the select box (focus event) rather than selects an element (which would be the change event)

Comment: I agree that it depends on the use case. My understanding was that OP needed a handler for every time the user opens the dropdown, which is why the suggested solution will not work IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery focus event will be your best bet: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/4V7QE/4/)

```
$('body').on('focus', 'select', function(){ ... });
```

Reference: [why to use .on() instead of .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878976/643482)

Comment: and what if I  use keyboard to access it. I'm amazed at how many `click` answers there are

Comment: agreed... it seems focus is your best bet:  `$('body').on('focus', 'select', function(){ ... });` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/4V7QE/4/)